# node.js how to respond .js files with parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, get

I have a node.js http application and i'm servicing GET requests ok. I can't however respond properly with requests for say foo.js?_param=1234. How do i deal correctly with files of this type where parameters are being passed?

EDIT:

I'm using express to service files as follows:

```
app.get('/*', function(req, res) {

  res.sendfile(__application+req.url, {root: __root});

});
```

__root is the root path of the application.

Answer (score 3):

Use `request.url`, it will look like `/foo.js?_param=123`.

Then use `require('url').parse(url,true)` to split this into meaningful parts (`true` is to also expand individual query string parameters).

See http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_url for details.

Comment: And yes, using a library like Express is still a good choice since it helps with much more than that

Comment: Thanks this works, however i'm not doing anything with the passed parameters and tbh i don't know how they work with a .js file. What i'm doing now is just extracting to the pathname from the request and passing this back. How should i correctly deal with the passed parameters?

Comment: Whatever you want. Read up how REST works for explanations, it's a good convention to follow. However, note that files that never change, like javascript files or CSS or images, are normally served statically, so you'd ignore any query params. Handling query parameters is useful for dynamically generated content like HTML pages (something like myblog.example.com/article.html?articleID=5&page=3).

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [express](http://expressjs.com/) module.

They have a whole API for dealing with GET and POST requests.

You can use [`req.query`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#req.query) to handle the get requests.

Comment: The reason to use a module for dealing with such things is that the node.js core modules are designed to be minimal.